# Tree Node Id not updating. Element UI Vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, element-ui

```
<el-tree :data="Project">
       <span class="custom-tree-node" slot-scope="{ node, data }" v-contextmenu:contextmenu>
            <el-input
              placeholder="Please input"
              v-model.trim="data.label"
              @blur="saveOrDiscard(node, data)"
            ></el-input>
          </span>
      </el-tree>
```

I have used method as below, where I am updating id of treenode (which is from ajax call inserted id. I have simply changed to clearly explain problem).

But data of tree (which I have given as Project) is not updating. Next time it shows 0 value (which I have set as deault).

```
public saveOrDiscard(node: TreeNode<any, TreeData>, data: TreeData) {

    //Following 456 is not updating in tree data.
    node.data.id = 456;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Binding blur event as following worked for me.

```
@blur="() => saveOrDiscard(node, data)"
```

instead of following.

```
@blur="saveOrDiscard(node, data)"
```

Answer (score 1):

**Scoped Slots and Slot Props**

`el-tree` is a slotted component and, by default, slots only have access to the same instance properties as the rest of the containing template. So for example, the slot does not have access to `:data`.

If you must access this data in the parent template, you need to use *slot props* and also explicitly bind the data in the slot's template.  So in the `el-tree` component template, you bind the data to the slot like this:

```
<slot :data="data"></slot>
```

Then in the parent template, you can access data via the `v-slot` directive like this:

```
<template v-slot:default="slotProps">
    {{ slotProps.data }}
</template>
```

The `default` argument refers to the slot name, which is named "default" if none is specified.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sh0ber/rj4fhevu/) showing this behavior.

*You can read more about slots & slot props [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Scoped-Slots).